# How to perform batch commands in terminal for files in each folder

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, pipe

I have a folder which contains some folders inside. In each folder there are some `bmp` files. I want to go inside each directory, convert `bmp` images to `pgm` format and remove original `bmp` files, and repeat for next directory.

e.g. folders are

```
.
..
folder-a
folder-b
```

And the command I want to use:

```
~/folder-a$ mogrify -format pgm *.bmp && rm *bmp
```

Is it possible to do this with a single command, e.g. piping `ls` result into `mogrify` commands? and not bother with a shell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find . -name "*.bmp" -exec mogrify -format pmg {} \; -exec rm {} \;`

Should do it from the toplevel folder. This will execute the second command only when the first one was successful.

If you want to execute both commands even the first one was not successfull you have to:

`find . -name "*.bmp" \( -exec mogrify -format pmg {} \; -o -exec true \; \) -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: While this should work, `find . -name "*.bmp" -exec mogrify -format pgm {} + -exec rm {} +` would be faster because it would fork less.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
for f in `ls`; do
  cd $f
  mogrify -format pmg *.bmp && rm *bmp
  cd ..
done
```

Or in one line:

```
for f in `ls`; do cd $f; mogrify -format pmg *.bmp && rm *bmp; cd ..; done
```

Comment: So use ; instead of newlines. Why the need for a single 'command'? It seems like a very arbitrary requirement.

Comment: This fails if the directory names contain whitespace.